# How to display elements of array, grouped by two in one <div>

Tags: php, css, html

I have an array of elements. I need to display all the elements on the page, grouped by two in one 'div' 
like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <article id='1'>item 1 row 1</article>
    <article id='2'>item 2 row 1</article>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <article id='3'>item 1 row 2</article>
    <article id='4'>item 2 row 2</article>
</div>
```

This my current php and html code:

```
<?php if ($arg['teasers']) foreach ($arg['teasers'] as $id => $article)
        { ?>

            <div class="shops_<?php echo ($article['show'])?'fair':'draft'; ?> more">     
            <div class="shops_title">
                <a href="<?php echo $arg['linkbase'].'/?id='.$id; ?>"><?php echo $article['title']; ?></a>

            </div>
            <div class="shops_teaser" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $arg['linkbase'].'/?id='.$id ?>'">
                <?php echo $article['teaser']; ?>
            </div>
            <?php show_button_detail(array('uri'=>$arg['linkbase'].'/?id='.$id)); ?>            
            </div>

        <?php 
        } ?>
```

Perfect example: http://tympanus.net/codrops/category/tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
/* div.more */
div.row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%; /* your parent element should specify a width for this to work */
}

/* div.more > div[class^="shops_"] */
div.row > article {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I'ts right, but i can't create 'div' with class='row' in my cicle. And now i have list: `<div class="shops_fair more">item 1</div>`  `<div class="shops_fair more">item 2</div>`  `<div class="shops_fair more">item 3</div>` without `<div class="row">`

Comment: The CSS comments aren't doing the job? I don't get it... Has your layout changed? I used `div.row` to help you visualize the idea. Once you know that then it should be easy to apply it to whatever code you have. You'll always need a way to identify the rows, either by using CSS classes in your HTML or cascading directly using CSS rules.

Comment: CSS doing all job, but i want change my layout, like in this example: [link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/category/tutorials/)  my current layout this: [link](http://1caas.ru/events/)

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. What's wrong with your current layout then? Is it because some divs aren't occupying the full height of their row? If so, then you do need extra divs (rows) embedding your groups of 2 divs (cells) so they know what height they should have.

Comment: " Is it because some divs aren't occupying the full height of their row?" - exactly! I want add extra divs (row), but i can't make it in my  cicle. Can you help me?

Comment: If you can't alter the DOM, then I think your best option is using JS... http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc